# Excel array formula - sum questionnaire results

Tags: arrays, excel

I have a spreadsheet that is collating the results of a site survey. Down column A I have the list of sites, and across the top I have the questions being asked. The questions fall into different categories, and each question may have a different weighting. The possible answers that can be used a Y, N, N/A or blank (blank being that the question was not answered). If the answer to a question is Y or N/A, they get the points for that question.

I can add up the total score easily enough:

```
{=SUM(($G6:$CE6="Y")*$G$3:$CE$3,($G6:$CE6="N/A")*$G$3:$CE$3)}
```

Row 6 being the row with the answers and row 3 being the row with the numeric weighting of the question.

Each question also has a category (e.g. QHSE, Finance, etc.). I want to also be able to add up scores for a specific category only but I'm struggling to create an array formula to do this.

I've tried a couple of things, e.g.:

```
{=SUM(IF($G$1:$CE$1="QHSE",IF(OR($G6:$CE6="Y",$G6:$CE6="N/A"),1,0)*1))}
```

Row 1 being the row which states the category of the question. I can't get any of these to work though.

I currently am using the following, which works fine, but like I said, I'd like to know if this is possible and how it would be done.

```
=SUMIFS($G$3:$CE$3,$G$1:$CE$1,$CO$1,$G6:$CE6,"Y")+SUMIFS($G$3:$CE$3,$G$1:$CE$1,$CO$1,$G6:$CE6,"N/A")
```

For example, if I had a much bigger list of possible answers that would score a point, it would be much easier to do something like the following that in would be to list out every single possible answer in the SUMIFS formula. (I know I can use a SUMIFS to achieve what I want but I've now got it in my head that it can be done this way so I now need to follow it through to the end.)

```
{=SUM(IF($G$1:$CE$1="QHSE",IF(OR($G6:$CE6=$DE$1:$DE$40),1,0)*1))}
```

Also, does anyone know using an array formula would compare efficiency wise to a SUMIFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular formula will do what you want (no array entry required):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($G$3:$CE$3,$G$1:$CE$1,$CO$1,$G6:$CE6,{"Y","N/A"}))
```

As for the second question in your post

> Also, does anyone know using an array formula would compare efficiency wise to a SUMIFS?

An Array formula will always be worse (efficiency wise) than a SUMIFS.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Exactly the kind of thing I was after

Answer (score 0):

Why not measure it using VBA.
Do the following in VBA:

- Set to manual calculation mode
- Take the current time
- Write your formula
- Calculate
- Take the current time
- Subtract from start time to get the calculated time.

Do the test with a large dataset to see a real difference.